# Error on TC SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, teamcity

I got TC installed in my VirutualBox VM with windows 7. Everything worked ok. But some days ago I switched my main system (host) from W7 to W10 and when I tried to get access to TC server I got following errors:

> SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG **in FF**

and

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR **in Chrome**

Strange thing is that I got the same errors in browsers even when I open pages in my VM. So maybe it just coincidence and doesn't connected with main system upgrade.

I’ve tried to fix the issue by upgrading TC to 2017 (before it was TC10). It started work in FF (but not in Chrome), but after some time I started to get same error.

How could I fix that?